What does it mean for particles to be created?
I am right now studying scalar (semi) quantum electrodynamics, i.e. a charged Klein Gordon field coupled to a background classical electric field in 1+1 spacetime dimensions.
The setup is as follows:

There are two charges $q$, $-q$ at two different points in space, $x=0$, and $x=1$.
1.1. Assume a Klein Gordon vacuum state between them.

These charges generate a (constant) electric field between them.

This electric field skews the positive frequency Klein-Gordon solutions in one direction and the negative frequency solutions in the other. (Thus polarizing the vacuum)


The question is: if the background electric field is strong enough so as to generate a particle anti-particle pair, how would one take that into account?
My intuition is:
The KG modes that would be torn apart into generating a particle anti-particle pair would be the first modes. If this happened, then what my intuition tells me is to solve the equations with now the charges that generate the background electric field given, instead of by q and -q, by (q-e) and -(q-e), and when solving for each mode of the KG equation, skipping the modes corresponding to these two particles?

If you haven't heard of it, a keyword that is worth searching and reading papers about is Schwinger pair production.
